# C++: Writing zero into .bmp file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read .bmp file, modify it's bitmap values, and write into another .bmp.

As far as I know, every "string" of pixels ends with zero, but the problem is that when I try to write that zero value, program crashes.

```
for (j = 0; j < height * mCoeff; j++)
{
    for (k = 0; k < width * mCoeff; k++)
    {
        fwrite(&newBitmap[j][k].red, 1, 1, output);
        fwrite(&newBitmap[j][k].green, 1, 1, output);
        fwrite(&newBitmap[j][k].blue, 1, 1, output);
    }
    fwrite(0, 1, 1, output); //crashes here
}
```

Error window: http://puu.sh/7Cxn1.png

What should I change in order to make it writing correctly?

Comment: It's probably a problem with your stream "output".  Have you checked return codes and made sure that "output" is valid before trying to write to it?

Comment: @rririwer
Everything is fine with the stream. It works well when something like
fread(&foo, 1, 1, input);
fwrite(&foo, 1, 1, output);
is writen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`frwite()` takes a pointer as its first argument. You're passing `0`, which happens to be a null pointer constant - so your program dereferences that null pointer and hits the assertion.

You need to pass a pointer as the first argument:

```
char zero = 0;
fwrite(&zero, 1, 1, output);
```

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of `fwrite` should be a `const void*` pointer pointing to the buffer that holds to the data to be written. You're passing a null pointer value (`0`) that is dereferenced inside `fwrite`, leading to undefined behaviour.

You need a proper object holding the zero:

```
char c = 0;
fwrite(&c, 1, 1, output);
```

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I know, every "string" of pixels ends with zero

This is incorrect, scanlines are 4-byte padded.

There should be 0, 1, 2 or 3 pad-bytes at the end, so that `scanlinesize % 4 == 0`

Comment: That's probably why I can open the resulting file. Guess you've just prevented me from asking another question, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, you've just made my course work I've been working at for a couple months work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
fwrite(0, 1, 1, output);
```

You're writing an invalid (null) pointer. Try writing that as a character instead:

```
char stringEnd = 0; //char 0 = \0
fwrite(&stringEnd, 1, 1, output);
```

Comment: @Angew I just tested, and my code segment does write `0` to the file. Why would it write the ASCII code of `0`? Or are you saying op is looking for `\0`, not `0`? I'm slightly confused.

Comment: @computerfreaker Angew is right, I'm not looking for writing ASCII code of zero symbol, but for code #0 or null. If you open a picture with hex-editor, you'll see there are zeros after every string of pixels. That's what i needed to write.

Comment: @user3441917 Ah, thanks for the clarification, I had misunderstood you. I'll edit my answer for correctness.